# I want to refresh the lightning-datatable automatically, if any record is edited

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, refreshapex

After editing the handleSubmit actually saves the data as shown:

```
handleSubmit(){
        var dataList = {};
        //newData is records the updated data.
        updateMapFieldData({mapFieldData : this.newData});
        this.closeEditModal();
        return refreshApex(this.data);
    }
```

data is sent to the lightning-datatable inorder to display the data.

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

data;
error;
@wire(getAllData, {recordId:'$recordid'})
    wiredData({error, data}) {
        if (data) {
            this.data = data;
        } else if(error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I tried refreshApex  but it didnt work, and I dont know what is the mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refresh apex does not work on just the data but the whole result of wired apex.
So you need to make some changes to your code.

```
wiredDataRes; 
@wire(getAllData, {recordId:'$recordid'})
wiredData(result) {
    this.wiredDataRes = result;
    let {error, data} = result;
    if (data) {
        this.data = data;
    } else if(error) {
        this.error = error;
    }
}
```

Now use the `result` with refresh apex.

```
refreshApex(this.wiredDataRes);
```

Comment: it is working, but the refresh is happening, for the 2nd edit. For example: If I am editing two times, then after the 2nd time the value of the 1st edit is visible.

Comment: @yashshah It will get called every time `handleSubmit` is called. Please check if its getting called correctly.

Comment: yes it worked this time, with minor changes at the handleSubmit

Comment: @yashshah was the name of the property the problem?

Comment: Yes the function name and the property name cannot be same. It threw an error for me. @rahulgawale